# What are some simple examples of "ID-only" rings? integral domains, that are neither atomic nor Noether nor Prüfer...

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Most common examples in the literature are rings of "higher virtues", having finite decompositions into irreducibles (maybe non-unique) -> atomic rings (Cohn), or Noether, or Prüfer, or GCD rings, or their intersections (UFD, Bézout, Dedekind and even more refined objects like PIDs, Eucl., fields). Why is it so much harder to find an easy "ID-only" ring?

Answer (score 1):

Using this [map at DaRT](https://web.archive.org/web/20211021142602/https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/maps/domain/) one would look for domains which are [not N-1](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/131/), [not Goldman](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=145), not Mori, and [not atomic](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/36/).  By avoiding these we dodge more stringent conditions too.

Interestingly, I did not realize there was no non-Mori domain confirmed yet, so thank you for asking.

I suppose we could additionally ask for a domain that isn't any of these four things, or at least combinations of them. But that gets complicated.

> Why is it so much harder to find an easy "ID-only" ring?

Of course, it is not really sensible to ask for an "ID-only ring" because the pool of conditions to avoid is potentially infinite. In general, every extra condition you have to dodge makes the problem that much harder. I think the best you could possibly hope to obtain is a domain that isn't the four things above, plus maybe some other conditions you are interested in that DaRT does not have.

---

Update:

It seems that I have been ignorant of another fact that will change the above map: Mori -> ACCP, so it actually is situated above atomic.  I will try to adapt this in the near future, and also include "noetherian" in there.

Comment: Great, thank you, Ryan!! take it that domain in yr chart actually stands for ID, and atomics comprise those that allow finite decompns into irreds.

Comment: Else we enter analysis/top. Albeit most useful in nonCR theory, Noetherian rings would come betw. Dedekind-D and ID's (and seem superfluous/seded in yr map, possibly replaced by the Krull-Mori branch?).  Indeed, a Mori domain need not be atomic nor Prüfer nor Noether and thus is an example close to what I searched for. It was not intended to go into an infinite loop of dodging further conditions. Still, I think it historically interesting that the meta-bag "ID" became filled with all these tasty fruit bags, rather than single unpacked melones ie. prototypical examples ;-)

Comment: @HaraldB All the properties are [defined on the site proper](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/) and are standard, with one exception maybe.

Comment: The maps are by no means comprehensive, but yeah I'm wishing I included Noetherian on there.

Comment: @HaraldB Hmm, it seems I use "ACC on divisiorial ideals" instead of "ACC on integral divisiorial ideals" for mori, and actually I find both online. But it looks like the latter is more standard.  And then now I'm appreciating that actually Mori-> ACCP, so that Mori shoudl be above atomic, now

Comment: Actually yr graphs on all ring and comm. ring properties do have Noether and also Artin rings indeed. just not the graph on ID's. They are more fundamental for noncomm.rings anyway - gotta make a choice somewhere! In general: do you require ring multiplicn. to form a semigroup or a monoid, ie. with a 1 (and 1 not zero for any nontrivial ring)?

Comment: @HaraldB the site only deals with rings with identity, otherwise things would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: yup, the arid lands of Rngs and algebras... no grps of units etc. Btway, good to see Ohio runs this ctr on ring theory! had a work stint in Dublin in 1983...   Merci!

Comment: @HaraldB arid? more like overgrown...